# ORA-24344: success with compilation errors while trying to create a function in plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, stored-functions

I am trying to create a function and everything seems to be going perfectly, except that I get some compilation errors from the highlighted lines

[image: Please open the image provided]

Comment: Edit your question and put the code *in the question as text*.

Comment: are you sure those APEX related packages installed properly?

Answer (score 0):

As long as Apex SQL Workshop allows you to execute (PL/)SQL code, it is rather difficult to debug that code. I'd suggest you to use another tool (such as SQL Developer), if possible  - which is not, if you run it on apex.oracle.com.

In that case (actually, in *any* case), you can try with

```
select * From user_errors where name = 'SALE_TOTAL_AMOUNT';
```

which will tell you what's wrong with your code. For example, you'll see something like

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following: ; The symbol ";" was substituted for "END" to continue.

(Note: I'm not saying that this is error you'll see. This is just an example of what you can expect.)

If you can't fix it, post the message back here and someone will assist.